# Book about space faring race that are very old but use swords and dress in black, also features a matriarchal society

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to remember a title for a very large older book that featured among other things a dying race of very tall, graceful people living on a desert planet. They live in a spire and have a matriarchal society.

I remember them dressing all in black and using swords.

Other points I remember:

- They leave the planet at some point (I think).
- They find ruins of their race that are very, very old.
- Main character also seemed to be a slightly rebellious young man.

I'll try and update if I remember anything else.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your question brings to my mind the [Faded Sun Trilogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faded_Sun_Trilogy) by C. J. Cherryh.

Comment: HaHa! That's it, I had read this years and years ago, and for about the last year have been trying to find this on google, and local book stores, but no one could point me in the right direction. Thanks! What's worse I could remember vaguely the artwork from the cover only when I described it at local bookstores they kept pointing me at this book: http://images1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20070607202924/sot/images/d/de/Pillars_of_Creation.jpg

Comment: Hmm. I've never read that book.

Comment: @Xantec it is highly recommended.