# Novel where the protagonist is integrated into alien society of desert dwellers

Tags: story-identification, aliens

A space-faring human is paid/contracted to integrate with a desert people who are VERY in-touch with the desert - a la Avatar?

I remember the desert people were taller and thinner than humans, used Saracen-style Scimitar swords, had their own alien language, and over the course of the book (books?) integrated this man into their society.

He ultimately went native -- I remember this because he would wear their robes, bathe with sand, and shave all of his body hair.

It's a book I read in the early 90's, and I would like to read it again, but my Google-Fu has failed me. :(

EDIT:  The desert people are used as bodyguard/mercenaries due to their excellent swordsmanship/fighting prowess and their very strict honor/belief system similar to Bushido.  They eschew technology, but are exposed to it enough that space travel is a non-issue.  The protagonist is also a space/war hero type person and generally considered an adept fighter until he meets the desert people.

I appreciate any pointers!

Comment: I'm reminded of Dune, but the Fremen of Arrakis were humans, not aliens. And I don't think Paul Atreides shaved all of his body hair.

Comment: Right, it's not DUNE, but similar enough that that series is all Google is returning.

Comment: I like how your edit makes it sound even more like Dune.

Comment: duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36486/book-about-space-faring-race-that-are-very-old-but-use-swords-and-dress-in-black

Comment: If it wasn't for the description of the protagonist being human (and the fact the answer was accepted) I'd have thought this to be "Black on Black" and its sequel "Stars Over Stars" by KD Wentworth.  The sand bath plus desert dwelling aliens is not a common combination, in my experience.

Comment: _Faded Sun_ is an excellent example of Cherryh taking all the concepts and conceits of a popular book (in this case _Dune_), disassembling them, examining how things actually work, and then reassembling them to make a consistent whole which tells a far more interesting story (c.f., Rimrunners/Starship Troopers)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That would be "[The Faded Sun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faded_Sun_Trilogy)" trilogy by C. J. Cherryh.!

[image]

composed of "Kesrith", "Shon'jir" and "Kutath".

Comment: That's exactly it!  THANKS!

EDIT:  It's amazing that I can ask the internet about "A book where some dude bathes with sand" and people know what I'm talking about.

THANKS!

Comment: The desert aliens are called [the Mri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mri_%28fictional_alien_species%29)